# Send Firebase API Notification with "extra information" using JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, http-post

I’m developing an android app and I am using the Firebase API to send push notification in android studio using HTTP POST. I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v29x4dKNBJw&feature=share/) to send the title and body. It works fine. I want to send extra information, Please suggest me how to achieve?. Here is my code:

```
            ...

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();                                                                     
            json.put("to", "/topics/" + "Greetings");

            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("title", "Hi");
            info.put("body", "Good morning");
            json.put("notification",info);

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("extra_information", PreferenceUtils.getUserID());
            json.put("extra_information", data);

            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase json payload looks like this:

```
[
    "to" => 'DEVICE_TOKEN',
    "notification" => [
        "body" => "SOMETHING",
        "title" => "SOMETHING",
        "icon" => "ic_launcher"
    ],
    "data" => [
        "ANYTHING EXTRA HERE"
    ]
]
```

Use the following for extras.

```
JSONObject extras = new JSONObject();
extras.put("message", "Happy birthday!");
extras.put("userId", PreferenceUtils.getUserID());
json.put("data",extras);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @farhanjk. I have tried it but the extra information is not received.

Comment: How are you checking if the `extra` information is received or not?

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now. Sorry for the late reply @farhanjk. The problem was how I was receiving the extra in the FirebaseMessagingService. I was receiving it with `remoteMessage.getNotification()` instead of `remoteMessage.getData()`.